# Create error message datefield

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I want to create an error message for following form:

```
class ExaminationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Examination
    fields = ['patient', 'number_of_examination', 'date_of_examination']
```

Models:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patientID = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='Insert PatientID')
    birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=Gender_Choice, default='UNDEFINED')

class Examination(models.Model):
    number_of_examination = models.IntegerField(choices=EXA_Choices)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_examination = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Every Patient has 2 Examinations (number of examination = Choices 1 or 2) and the error message should be activated when the date of the second examination < date of the first examination. Something like this:

Solution: `

```
def clean_date_of_examination(self):
        new_exam = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_examination')
        try:
            old_exam = Examination.objects.get(patient=self.cleaned_data.get('patient'))
        except Examination.DoesNotExist:
            return new_exam

        if old_exam:
            if old_exam.date_of_examination > new_exam:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Second examination should take place after first examination")
        return new_exam`
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: Yes, please, share your models, because I think my answer maybe wrong!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but I have a feeling that my answer is wrong because you are not quite explicit to your question!

Comment: When the date of the second examination is BEFORE the date of the first examination it should give an error. This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think it is the last if loop. The query with pat1.date_of_examination is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clean_date_of_examination(self):
    new_exam = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_examination')
    old_exam = Examination.objects.get(patient = self.cleaned_data.get('Patient'))
    if old_exam:
        if old_exam.date_of_examination > new_exam.date_of_examination:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Second examination should take place after first examination")
    return data
```

Comment: I added the "try/except" statement to your definition but got the error: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date_of_examination' for the last if statement also I replace the data with new_exam is this right?

Comment: Got the issue! Instead of "new_exam.date_of_examination" it should be "new_exam"

Comment: Yes after adding the "try/except" statement and fixing the last "if ..." it worked. Thanks a lot. Upvoted you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_date_of_examination(self):
    # Where 'data' is used?
    date_of_exam = self.cleaned_data['date_of_examination']

    try:
        pat1 = Patient.object.get(examination__number_of_examination=1, date_of_examination=date_of_exam)
    except Patiens.DoesNotExist:
        # Patient 1 with given query doesn't exist. Handle it!
    try:
        pat2 = Patient.object.get(examination__number_of_examination=2, date_of_examination=date_of_exam)
    except Patiens.DoesNotExist:
        # Patient 2 with given query doesn't exist. Handle it!

    if pat2.date_of_examination < pat1.date_of_examination:
         raise forms.ValidationError("Second examination should take place after first examination")`
    return data`
```

Comment: Should have give you my models sorry! Updated my question :)

Comment: And what is the `data`? This is passed through your form to get the patient with this date?

Comment: to be honest: I just saw it in on of the Django docs and thought this is necessary to return something. But maybe it is just nonesense. I have tried your code but to get number_of_examination it should be "examination__number_of_examination" and when I edited this it says "Patient matching query does not exist"

Comment: This means that the `Patient` record with `number_of_examination=1` and `date_of_examination='date-from-form'` does not exist. Updated my answer to catch these exceptions